# copy git directory changes both directories with git checkout

Tags: git, ssh, terminal, repository

I have been searching high and low for anyone who might know why the following is happening and had no luck. I am really hoping someone here understands what is going on and can help because I am so lost.

Here is what is going on, we have multiple (2) directories for each developer on this project, a private and a public. I ran into a problem where I was on my private folder, we'll call it 'source' and I did a 'git checkout -b branch_name_here' worked on everything I needed to work on, then did a commit and a push... 'git push origin branch_name_here' so it is now on the main repo. I then went into my public folder, we'll call it 'pub_source' and tried to pull it... 'git checkout branch_name_here' but that popped an error saying stuff about not having tracking history and all that, so in a frenzy I just went into a terminal window and did this...

```
rm -rf pub_source
cp -R source pub_source
```

and that worked, now my pub_source had the correct files in it and I could show everyone things are working. Now the problem comes in, I go back into my source folder and do 'git checkout master', thinking everything was cool, it wasn't! what happened was both source and pub_source changed to master??

So i am super confused and now I can't change my source branch without ruining my pub directory. I'll run through the commands down here so you can see exactly what happened..

```
ssh <<SERVER NAME>>
cd source //that takes me to my "working" directory and git repo
git checkout -b <<BRANCH NAME>>
//Work on files and get things fixed
git add -A //There were a lot of files and this is easier
git commit -m "blah blah"
git push origin <<BRANCH NAME>>
cd .. //takes me back to my home dir
rm -rf pub_source //Delete the pub directory
cp -R source pub_source //now pub source has all the new files and is on the right branch
cd source // back into working dir
git checkout master
```

after that git checkout master line, both source, and pub_source switch to master. Now anytime I do anything in source dealing with branches, i.e. git checkout "ANOTHER BRANCH" both source and pub_source change to the "ANOTHER BRANCH".
I really hope I am explaining this correctly, and I really really hope that someone can see what is going on and how I can get my source folder to be able to change branches without also changing my pub_source. Thank you in advance for any help you might have.

On a side note I know that if I had done 'git checkout -b <> origin' I would've had tracking info and could have then done a pull in pub, but I didn't and now I'm stuck. Please help. Thank you

Comment: Can you check if source or pub_source is a symbolic link? Run `ls -l` in the directory containing them to see. If one of them is, it will look something like `source -> pub_source`

Comment: Try `git checkout -b foobranch origin/foobranch` in your `pub_source`

Comment: @Khaelid there are no sym links, I ran that code and nothing like that showed up. there are sym links inside but only to other folder containing images for the site.
 MNIIP - that worked, and pub_source is on that, but if I now go to source and do git checkout <anything here it doesn't matter> pub_source also changes, but doesn't show that it changed in the logs, only way I can tell is view in browser and it is the wrong code